# How to simplify $\Re\left[\sqrt2 \tan^{-1} {x\over \sqrt i}\right]$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

While solving $$\int \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}\,dx,$$ I tried to use partial fractions in the denominator by writing $x^4+1=(x^2+i)(x^2-i)$ And then I got $\Re\left[\sqrt2 \tan^{-1}{x\over \sqrt i}\right]$. In my book they used another method without complex numbers and they got $\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x^2-1}{x\sqrt2}\right)$. How do I prove my answer is equal to theirs? I tried the realtions between log and atan but I couldnt get rid of the $i$. **Edit:** Please note that this question is not about solving the integral (which I already solved to get $\Re\left[\sqrt2 \tan^{-1}{x\over \sqrt i}\right]$.) but about the simplification of the answer I got using complex partial fractions method to reduce it to the real part only.

Comment: You might want to use that $\arctan x = \frac{1}{2i} \log \left( \frac{1+ix}{1-ix} \right)$

Comment: Yes, i tried that too but the $\sqrt i$ still remains within log. I tried many times, wasted 5-6 Pages of my notebook but still did not get anywhere . .

Comment: Differentiate both results, they *must* be equal. If they are equal, then they differ integrated only by a constant, which can be easily determined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\Re\left[\sqrt2 \tan^{-1}{x\over \sqrt i}\right]=\Re\left[\sqrt2 \tan^{-1}{x\cdot e^{-i\pi/4}}\right]=\frac{(\sqrt2 \tan^{-1}{x\cdot e^{-i\pi/4}})+(\sqrt2 \tan^{-1}{x\cdot e^{i\pi/4}})}{2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \tan^{-1}{x\cdot e^{i\pi/4}}+\tan^{-1}{x\cdot e^{-i\pi/4}} \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{x\cdot e^{i\pi/4}+x\cdot e^{-i\pi/4}}{1-x\cdot e^{i\pi/4}\cdot x\cdot e^{-i\pi/4}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{2x\cos \frac{\pi}{4}}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{1-x^2}$$

where line $2\to3$ is achieved by using that $\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1- \tan x \tan y}$.

The differs from the expression you give by a constant, after further noting that $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I nearly forgot about the formula atan a + atan b. .

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misunderstood the visualization code. thank you for the answer! very instructive!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}=\dfrac{1+\dfrac1{x^2}}{\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+2}$$

Now $\dfrac{d\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)}{dx}=?$

Comment: I know this, it is the method given in our book. I want to know how to do it using complex numbers, because this method is not very general. It works only for Quadratic/Biquadratic type.

Answer (score 0):

$$  x^4 + 1 = (x^2 + \sqrt 2 \; x + 1) (x^2 - \sqrt 2 \; x + 1) $$

Comment: I know that but i want to know how to simplify my answer.