# How to prove a fomula is real or not?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, numerical-methods

The formula is:

$$f(u):=\sqrt{1+i}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{(-1+i)u}}\right)+\sqrt{1-i}\arctan\left(\frac{(-1)^{3/4}\sqrt{(-1-i)u}}{u}\right)\tag{1}$$

I obtained it from the following definite integral:
$$f(u):=\int_u^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-2 x+2} \, dx\quad {\text{ where }} u>0\tag{2}$$

Numercial estimation indicates that, when $u>0$, $f(u)\in \mathbb{R}$ because the imaginary part of the results are close to numerical epsilon.

How to prove or disprove it? If the conclusion is true, is it possible to eliminate the imaginary unit $i$ from the fomula of $f(u)$ in $(1)$ and obtain a relatively *simpler* form of it which does not contain or implies any imaginary number?

**update**

$$f^*(u):=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \left(\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \left(\ln \left(u-\sqrt{2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)} \sqrt{u}+\sqrt{2}\right)-\ln \left(u+\sqrt{2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)} \sqrt{u}+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-2 \arctan\left(-\sqrt{2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)} \sqrt{u}+\sqrt{2}+1\right)+2 \arctan\left(\sqrt{2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)} \sqrt{u}+\sqrt{2}+1\right)-2 \pi \right)$$

Comment: As an integral can be expressed as an area the result must be a real number. But as for how to express it without the $i$ I don't think you can write it in a closed form without $i$.

Comment: The integrand is quite nice (just plot it) for $x\geq 0$; so the result must be real (think about the area under the curve). By the way, I got something different but as awful as your formula but I did not find any simplification. Sorry !

Comment: I suspect that for $u>0$, the second term is just the complex conjugate of the first. Since $z+\bar z = 2\Re(x)$, this would imply that $f(u)$ is real. However there are some complexities [no pun intended] with the definition of the square root and $(-1)^{3/4}$.

Comment: @user6043040 I converted your primitive $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-2 x+2}$ using only real functions (see my answer). I followed the procedure described here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848283/how-to-simplify-re-left-sqrt2-tan-1-x-over-sqrt-i-right?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [How to simplify $\Re\left[\sqrt2 \tan^{-1} {x\over \sqrt i}\right]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848283/how-to-simplify-re-left-sqrt2-tan-1-x-over-sqrt-i-right?rq=1)
I manage to write a primitive of $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-2 x+2}$ using real functions. Let
$$F(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}}\cdot 
\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}\cdot \sqrt{x}}{x-\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
$$G(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+2}}\cdot 
\mbox{arctanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+2}\cdot\sqrt{x}}{x+\sqrt{2}}\right),$$
then you can [verify](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff(-arctan((-2%2B2*2%5E(1%2F2))%5E(1%2F2)*x%5E(1%2F2)%2F(x-2%5E(1%2F2)))%2F(-2%2B2*2%5E(1%2F2))%5E(1%2F2)-arctanh((2*2%5E(1%2F2)%2B2)%5E(1%2F2)*x%5E(1%2F2)%2F(x%2B2%5E(1%2F2)))%2F(2*2%5E(1%2F2)%2B2)%5E(1%2F2),x)) that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(-F(x)-G(x)\right)= \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-2 x+2}.$$

Comment: Thank you! The link is very useful! BTW, it seems such a construction highly depends on computation softwares, am I right?