# Closed form for this $\text{I}(u)=\int_u^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x$ integral? (spot my mistake)

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Solving [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890943/how-to-prove-a-fomula-is-real-or-not#1890943), I came up with this (but mathematica gives me a different answer, also when I use a value for $u$) can someone spot my mistake?

My work:

$$\text{I}(u)=\int_u^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_u^n\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $s=\sqrt{x}$ and $\text{d}s=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\space\text{d}x$.

This gives a new lower bound $s=\sqrt{u}$ and upper bound $s=\sqrt{n}$:

---

$$2\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{s^2}{s^4-2s^2+2}\space\text{d}s=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{s^2}{\left(s^2-(1+i)\right)\left(s^2-(1-i)\right)}\space\text{d}s=$$

---

Use partial fractions, I set:

- $$\text{z}=\frac{1+i}{2}\to\overline{\text{z}}=\frac{1-i}{2}$$
- $$\text{q}=1+i\to\overline{\text{q}}=1-i$$

  ---

$$2\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{n}}\left[\frac{\text{z}}{s^2-\overline{\text{q}}}+\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{s^2-\text{q}}\right]\space\text{d}s=$$
$$2\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\text{z}\cdot\int_{\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{s^2-\overline{\text{q}}}\space\text{d}s+\overline{\text{z}}\cdot\int_{\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{s^2-\text{q}}\space\text{d}s\right]=$$

---

Substitute, for the left integral $t=\frac{s}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}$ and $\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}\space\text{d}s$.

This gives a new lower bound $t=\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}$ and upper bound $t=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}$:

Substitute, for the right integral $v=\frac{s}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}$ and $\text{d}v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}\space\text{d}s$.

This gives a new lower bound $v=\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}$ and upper bound $v=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}$:

---

$$-2\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{\text{z}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}\cdot\int_{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}\frac{1}{1-t^2}\space\text{d}t+\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}\cdot\int_{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}\frac{1}{1-v^2}\space\text{d}v\right]=$$

---

Now, use:

$$\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\ln\left|\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right|}{2}+\text{C}$$

---

$$-2\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{\text{z}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}\cdot\left[\frac{\ln\left|\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right|}{2}\right]_{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}+\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}\cdot\left[\frac{\ln\left|\frac{v+1}{v-1}\right|}{2}\right]_{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}\right]=$$
$$-2\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{\text{z}}{2\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}\cdot\left[\ln\left|\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right|\right]_{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}+\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{2\sqrt{\text{q}}}\cdot\left[\ln\left|\frac{v+1}{v-1}\right|\right]_{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}\right]=$$
$$-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{\text{z}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}\cdot\left[\ln\left|\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right|\right]_{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}+\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}\cdot\left[\ln\left|\frac{v+1}{v-1}\right|\right]_{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}}\right]=$$
$$-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{\text{z}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}\cdot\left(\ln\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|-\ln\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|\right)+\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}\cdot\left(\ln\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|-\ln\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|\right)\right]=$$

---

Set:

$$\text{s}=\frac{\text{z}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}\to\overline{\text{s}}=\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}$$

---

$$-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\text{s}\cdot\left(\ln\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|-\ln\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|\right)+\overline{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\ln\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|-\ln\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|\right)\right]=$$

---

Assume $u\space\wedge\space n\in\mathbb{R}^+$:

- $$\text{A}=\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\overline{\text{q}}}}-1}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{u}\cdot\sqrt{2(1+\sqrt{2})}+u}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{u}\cdot\sqrt{2(1+\sqrt{2})}+u}}$$
- $$\text{B}=\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}+1}{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\text{q}}}-1}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{2(1+\sqrt{2})}+n}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{2(1+\sqrt{2})}+n}}$$

---

$$-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\text{s}\cdot\left(\ln\left(\text{B}\right)-\ln\left(\text{A}\right)\right)+\overline{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\ln\left(\text{B}\right)-\ln\left(\text{A}\right)\right)\right]=-\left(\text{s}+\overline{\text{s}}\right)\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\ln\left(\text{B}\right)-\ln\left(\text{A}\right)\right]=$$

---

Notice:

- $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{2(1+\sqrt{2})}+n}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{2(1+\sqrt{2})}+n}}=1$$
- $$\text{s}+\overline{\text{s}}=2\Re[\text{s}]=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}}$$

  ---

$$\left(\text{s}+\overline{\text{s}}\right)\ln\left(\text{A}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\ln\left(\text{A}\right)$$

Comment: According to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890943/how-to-prove-a-fomula-is-real-or-not#1890943 you simply have that $I(u)=F(u)+G(u)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RobertZ I saw your answer on that question, but that do not answer my question. Because where am I going a wrong path in my work solving the integral?

Comment: it takes a little bit longer to make all you computations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the indefinitiv integral is given by $$-\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{-1-i}}\right)}{(-1-i)^{3/2}}-\frac{2 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{-1+i}}\right)}{(-1+i)^{3/2}}$$
i hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not what I'm asking. I want to find the mistake in my work. And for completeness, my variable is an $u$ not a $x$ :)